# Not quite awarded badge glitch?

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress, electorate-badge

Glitch with a recently 'earned' badge. Upon finally casting my 600th qualifying vote on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81263/ouflak) for the [electorate-badge](/questions/tagged/electorate-badge), the display did this.:

[image]


**24 of 25?** So then I took a peak at the 'Select your next badge' page, and it shows this:



[image]


Normally a badge disappears off this page once it's prerequisites are fulfilled (even if you don't immediately get it awarded). I've gotten another badge on the site since then, so it's not a log jam there. Is this a particular issue with this badge maybe?

***Edit:*** In case anybody is curious, I finally got my coveted electorate a day after this was posted.

Comment: 2,446 up / 603 questions = 24.65249387%. So, ~ 14 more questions, or 2460/617=25.08%

Comment: There are plenty of excellent questions on Code Golf. Should be no problem....

Comment: Doh! I've run out of votes for answers to my own recent question. * sigh *

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you still don't meet the criteria for the badge. Yes, you cast 600 votes on questions, but only 24% of your votes were on questions, while 25% is required. So the '24/25' is correct (but 24%/25% would make more sense), and the 'Select your next badge' dialog should display this progress as well, instead of '602/600'.

Comment: So there is a slight glitch then?

Comment: Let's say that the functionality can be slightly improved...

Answer (score 5):

There are two separate requirements for that badge. The 24 of 25 represents the percentage of your votes that are on questions. Only 24% of your votes are on questions, but the badge requires at least 25%.

You simply need to vote on more questions.